# How can I Declare/define/initialize a static member variable of template classes as static member variables of a class?

Tags: c++, templates, static

I have the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
    public:
        static int a;
};

class B {
    public:
        static A<int> a1;
        static A<double> a2;
};

int B::a1::a = 0; --> It gives an error "a1 is not a class, namespace, enumeration"
```

(I am using llvm compiler in XCode. I can reproduce the problem with gcc as well.)

How can I Declare/define/initialize a static member variable of template classes as static member variables of a class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static members are defined base on their class. `a` is static member of `A`, `a1` and `a2` are static members of `B`, you can't mix up their definition.

Define them seprately:

```
template <typename T>
int A<T>::a = 0;

A<int> B::a1;
A<double> B::a2;
```

If you want template specialization for definition of `A<T>::a`, it will look like:

```
template <typename T>
int A<T>::a = 0;
template <typename T>
int A<int>::a = 1;
template <typename T>
int A<double>::a = 2;
```

Then for `A<int>::a` the initial value will be `1`, for `A<double>::a` will be `2`, for other types like `A<char>::a` it will be `0`. Note the definitions is still independent of the definitions of class `B`.

If you want to access `a` from `B::a1`, you could write `B::a1.a`; since `a1` is a `A<int>`, the result is same as `A<int>::a`.

Comment: Further, you should define the template member `A<T>::a` in the header, along with the rest or the template, and the (non-template) members of `B` in a source file.

Comment: Isn't 'a' a static member variable for each of A<int> and A<double>, not one of A? (There is no class called 'A'. Only A<int> and A<double> I think?)

Comment: @syko Yes, `A<int>` has a static member `a`, and `A<double>` has its own static `a`. The above definition will be used for these cases. So if you use `A<int>`, `A<int>::a` will be defined, if you use `A<char>`, `A<char>::a` will be defined...

Comment: @songyuanyao thanks. then how can I access 'a' of a1 of B? 'B::a1::a' does not work neither for referencing.

Comment: @syko It should be `B::a1.a`; Since `a1` is a `A<int>`, the result is same as `A<int>::a`.